# Trying to save file to directory using Python, but it does not work

Tags: python, file, directory, path

So i have this code:

```
def setVideoConfig(self):
        filename1=f'records/{self.helpers.filename()}CAMARA1.avi'
        filename2=f'records/{self.helpers.filename()}CAMARA2.avi'
        self.videofile1=cv2.VideoWriter(filename1,self.fourcc,self.FRAMES_VIDEO,self.RESOLUCION_VIDEO)
        self.videofile2=cv2.VideoWriter(filename2,self.fourcc,self.FRAMES_VIDEO,self.RESOLUCION_VIDEO)
    
    def screenshot(self,frame1,frame2):
        cv2.imwrite(f'record\{self.helpers.filename()}CAMARA1.jpg',frame1)
        cv2.imwrite(f'record\{self.helpers.filename()}CAMARA2.jpg',frame2)
```

I think it should save the file in this directory called **records**, i tried using different slashes just in case but gotted the same result. But when i do:

```
def setVideoConfig(self):
        filename1=f'{self.helpers.filename()}CAMARA1.avi'
        filename2=f'{self.helpers.filename()}CAMARA2.avi'
        self.videofile1=cv2.VideoWriter(filename1,self.fourcc,self.FRAMES_VIDEO,self.RESOLUCION_VIDEO)
        self.videofile2=cv2.VideoWriter(filename2,self.fourcc,self.FRAMES_VIDEO,self.RESOLUCION_VIDEO)
    
    def screenshot(self,frame1,frame2):
        cv2.imwrite(f'{self.helpers.filename()}CAMARA1.jpg',frame1)
        cv2.imwrite(f'{self.helpers.filename()}CAMARA2.jpg',frame2)
```

Just deleting the records part text and leaving the filename, it does save them

```
def filename():
    actual=datetime.now()
    date=actual.strftime("%H-%M-%S")
    return date
```

Any ideas? :(

Comment: Does the directory `records` already exist?

Comment: @Julien OH GOD i though it would create it automatically, thank you very much